# Razor Generator: Is this accurate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, razorgenerator, pre-compilation

I recently queried the former Lead Developer at my current place of employment as to why he chose to use the ***Razor Generator*** to pre-compile our views in to a separate assembly.

He made some claims below, but I can't seem to find any ***Razor Generator*** profiles and/or metrics on the web to back up the claim (10-100 times faster), and/or, if what ***IIS7/ASP.NET*** does behind the scenes regarding pre-compiled vs. runtime-compiled views and their benefit or the lack-there-of.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Or comment?

It seems to me (as far as startup time is concerned) simply setting IIS `autostart = true` for the site would balance out any benefit of pre-compiling using the ***Razor Generator***.  Here is his statement:

Why are we using the Razor Generator to pre-compile our views and why put them in a separate assembly?

> The first is simple, compile-time error checking. With this many views
>   it seemed like a great way to avoid errors on production. It's a bit
>   frustrating having to recompile to see the changes to the views I
>   admit, but it is (in my opinion) totally worth it to know that you
>   have that much more error checking upfront.
>
> The second is that when the views aren't compiled in a project they
>   get compiled at runtime and then those compiled representations have
>   to be stored in ram. Sometimes, if they're not accessed regularly
>   (which is the case with most of those views since there are so many)
>   those stored compiled versions get abandoned and garbage collected to
>   save ram. So all but the most frequently accessed views in a site like
>   gaf.com end up being recompiled every time they are accessed. But if
>   you put them in a project the compiled versions just need to be loaded
>   from the dll if it's not already in memory (yes code can be garbage
>   collected too, but less often). Loading that from the dll is 10 - 100
>   times faster (that's from the Razor Generator project's site - I
>   didn't verify it myself, but it sounds reasonable).

Comment: All his points are technically true. Feel free to read my experiences and solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866711/asp-net-mvc-mvcbuildviews-increasing-compile-time-drastically/14867003#14867003

Comment: why not add it as a response so I can mark it as the answer, if you throw in how pre-compiling stacks up to iis7 auto start?

Comment: I hope this speaks to the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We struggled with the same problem. We began compiling Views in order to catch obvious issues that would creep up on us during **Integration Tests** and **UX Tests**. Even worse were the bugs that somehow crept into production.

But, our build times became intolerable. Our developers build countless times and that became a major part of our day. We had jokes about testing after lunch so the build could be done while we were out.

We eventually moved to building before **UX-tests**.

---

Now we are moving toward pre-compiling. Only one guy on our team has adopted it for now and apparently pre-compiles are noticably better than builds (incremental vs total). And setup is basically a nuget fetch.

These articles should be a good start

http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/01/19/precompiling-razor-views-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-3/

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html

---

Pre-compiling gives us all the advantages of deploying ready built binaries. Our users don't experience the momentary lag the first time a View is hit.

As far as I know `IIS autostart = true` will start you Application Pool but will not force compile your Views. As a result, you're left with the initial start-up hit for the first user to use each View.