# MvcBuildViews in MS2015 takes a long time

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, teamcity, roslyn

We are converting a solution to use the new Roslyn compiler. When I build it via teamCity in release mode, the MVCBuildViews step still uses aspnet_compiler.exe and it takes about 15 minutes to precompile views. The same process used to take 3 minutes using the previous version of aspnet_compiler.exe on .NET 4.5

This is the command that takes a while:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v temp -p E:\path\to\web\project\Directory

I have tried tweaking the MSBuild parameters but nothing changed. is this a known issue, are there any work around, Do I need to pre-compile the view with Roslyn ?
what is the drawback for turning turn off the MVCBuildViews step if it is an option ( I believe our choice to pre-compile on release is what causes this step to run).

Answer (score 6):

We've hit the same issue at Stack Overflow, that's why we created [StackExchange.Precompilation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation). You can read about it in [our announcement blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/announcing-stackexchange-precompilation/), but here are some gory technical details, as we, naturally, investigated *why* `aspnet_compiler.exe` was so slow, before writing our own replacement for it.

`aspnet_compiler.exe` has been around long before [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and [razor](/questions/tagged/razor), and of course, it supported stuff like batch compilation via `<compilation batch="true" />`. In order for a view to be compiled though, the CSHTML template has to be transformed into C# (CodeDOM), first. Unfortunately, this isn't *compilation* as such, so `batch="true"` doesn't apply to it. (in-)Effectively, views are processed in sequence, one view at a time. And any roslyn features you add on top of it only slow it down, since there has to be a CodeDOM -> roslyn conversion at some point.

Here's a nice stack trace, of what's going on before a *batch* compilation in `aspnet_compiler.exe` takes place.

[image: aspnet_compiler.exe foreach loop]

Notice [this AddBuildProvider call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Compilation/BuildProvidersCompiler.cs,188) (which calls [GenerateCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs,470)) is already inside two `foreach` loops. I guess the `batch="true"` options was only ever effective at speeding up the compilation of `App_Code` in Website Projects...

This is what happened to our build times afterwards:

[image]

I wouldn't recommend disabling the precompilation to anybody running an ASP.NET MVC app in production.

- The most obvious argument for it is, that it verifies you view code. Otherwise, you trade compile-time errors on the build server for run-time errors, in production.
- The other argument for it is performance. Your views have to be compiled at some point, and if it doesn't happen at compile-time, the first few users that hit your site have to wait, again, in production.

Comment: Thanks! I will explore StackExchange.Precompilation. And pass along any feedback. Kudos to you guys at StackExchange for the good work you do.